# Select dinámico y opción por defecto desde Sql

Tags: sql, select

Tengo un `SELECT` dinámico de Países:

> "Peru, Chile, Ecuador, Colombia"

Si desde la base de datos obtengo un registro por ejemplo Ecuador. 
¿Como le hago para que este quede seleccionado por defecto en el `Select`? `html5`

Comment: EL opcion seleccionade es asi <option selected value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>

Comment: Los elementos `option` de HTML poseen un atributo llamado `selected`, es un atributo booleano (verdadero o falso) el cual _Si está presente, indica si esta opción es la inicialmente seleccionada._ En un grupo de `option` aparecerá seleccionado por defecto aquel que tenga ese atributo indicado: `<option selected value="valor">Texto</option>`. Para más detalles puedes ver la [doc sobre el atributo `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option) De todos modos la pregunta no es del todo clara.

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos `option` de HTML poseen un atributo llamado `selected`, es un atributo booleano (verdadero o falso) el cual:

> Si está presente, indica si esta opción es la inicialmente
>   seleccionada.

En un grupo de `option` aparecerá seleccionado por defecto aquel que tenga ese atributo indicado, por ejemplo:

`<option selected value="valor">Texto</option>`.

Para más detalles puedes ver la [doc sobre el atributo `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option) .

Si quieres que aparezca ese atributo por defecto, al obtener los datos de la base de datos deberás guardar en una variable **aquel** que quieras ver seleccionado y luego **compararlo** con los diferentes elementos al momento de construir cada elemento del select.

Como no das más detalles en la pregunta la respuesta no puede ser más exacta.

Imaginemos un escenario en el que consultas a tu base de datos de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT pais FROM paises ORDER BY pais_id;
```

Obteniendo tus resultados en un arreglo.

Según el entorno en que estés manejando tus datos (que tampoco lo indicas), obtienes el primer elemento de los resultados devueltos y lo guardas en una variable.

Imaginemos que lo estás manejando con PHP...

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](https://rextester.com/NSUVD94952)</kbd>

**php**

```
<?php

    $paises=
        array(
                "Perú" => "Perú",
                "Bolivia" => "Bolivia",
                "Ecuador" => "Ecuador",
                "Chile" => "Chile",);

    /*
        *Indicamos el valor seleccionado
        *Se necesitan más detalles en la pregunta para determinar 
        *otra técnica de selección como por ejemplo obtener el primer 
        *elemento del array, el último elemento, etc 

    */

    $selected="Ecuador";

    // Creamos una variable para ir concatenando
    $html="<select>";

    foreach ($paises as $k=>$v)
    {
        $html.="<option value='$k'";

        //Preguntamos por la llave del array y la comparamos con la variable $selected

        if ($k==$selected) $html.=" selected=$selected";
        $html.=">$v</option>";
    }

    // Cerramos e imprimos el select

    $html.='</select>';
    echo $html;    

?>
```

**resultado**

```html
<select>
  <option value='Perú'>Perú</option>
  <option value='Bolivia'>Bolivia</option>
  <option value='Ecuador' selected>Ecuador</option>
  <option value='Chile'>Chile</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu respuesta, mira soy completamente nuevo y sin nada de experiencia, te indico: Como se muestra en la imagen ya realizo la consulta sql para que me cargen los paises desde la base de datos, ahora quiero dejar seleccionado por defecto (por ejemplo ECUADOR) como le hago para dejar seleccionado ese pais en el ciclo?  Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]